# HTML, CSS - Aligning Button To The Center of Page

Tags: html, css

May I please know how can I align the `login button` to the center of the page? I can't seem to do it althoughI've tried many suggestions from previous posts like this.

Need help on this.

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.buttonlogin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

button {
  background-color: FireBrick;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  margin: auto;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <button class="buttonlogin" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:10%;">Login</button>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given your button a `position` of `absolute`, so you're looking to also apply `left: 50%`. **However**, you probably actually also want to subtract the **offset** from your width, so that the element remains perfectly in the center. In this case, you're looking for `left: 45%`, as the element has a `width` of `10%`. The same goes for `top`, which can be calculated with 
`calc(50% - (48px / 2))`:

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.buttonlogin {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - (48px / 2));
  left: 45%; /*calc(50% - (10% / 2)); */
}

button {
  background-color: FireBrick;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  margin: auto;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <button class="buttonlogin" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:10%;">Login</button>
  </div>

</body>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, your explanations and codes are understandable ! Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
.buttonlogin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This put the button at the center of the html.

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.buttonlogin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  background-color: FireBrick;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  margin: auto;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button class="buttonlogin" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:10%;">Login</button>

</body>
```

Comment: You're welcome mate. Please consider accepting my answer so other people know it's an answered question.

Answer (score -1):

Add this:

```
button {
    left : 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, really do appreciate it. It worked but it doesn't really align to the center, instead, it went slightly above 50% of the left side. I added this line `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` and it worked perfectly. :)

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

```css
.wrapper{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button> Sample </button>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, this helped too but just that it doesn't align to the center of the page. However, thanks a bunch for your time. Really appreciate it ! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<body>
<table style="width:100%;height:100%">
<tr><td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle">
<button>Click me</button>
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```